# React Native - Retrieve Value from PassProps Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I get the parameter from passProps on the new route? Passing from 'Home' to 'Single'. Confirmed the values are parsed just not sure how to retrieve them on single.js?

```
//index.ios.js
class AwesomeNativeBase2 extends Component {

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if(route.name == 'single') {
      return <Single navigator={navigator} />
    }
    if(route.name == 'home') {
      return <Home navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
    }
    if(route.name == 'update') {
      return <Update navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={{name: 'home'}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

//home.js
class Home extends Component {
  navigate(routeName, property) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: routeName,
      passProps: {
        id: property
      }
    });
  }

//single.js
class Single extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.navigator.pop());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as it being done for other routes, add it as below

```
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if(route.name == 'single') {
      return <Single navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
    }
   ....
  }
```

And inside of `Single` component, access the properties of `passProps` as `this.props.id`